# Microsoft Graph API v5: Retrieving child objects no longer working

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Recently upgraded nuget packge from v4.x to v5.x for MicrosoftGraph noting the changes at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md

Simplified code for v4.x worked:

```
var queryOptionsForDocs = new List<QueryOption>()
{
  new QueryOption("expand", "listitem"),
  new QueryOption("top","999")
};

var allDocuments = await graphServiceClient
               .Sites["SomeSiteId"]
               .Drives["SomeDriveId"]
               .Root
               .ItemWithPath("SomePath")
               .Children
               .Request(queryOptionsForDocs)
               .GetAsync();

//Further filter them on the client side as some of the documents have custom metadata in the format of "Public=true"
var publicDocuments = allDocuments.Where(m => m.ListItem?.Fields.AdditionalData.Where(j => j.Key == "Public" && j.Value.ToString().ToLower() == "true").ToList().Count > 0).ToList();
```

but my new v5.x code is not working:

```
var allDocuments = await graphServiceClient.Drives["SomeDriveId"].Root.ItemWithPath(path).Children.GetAsync(r => { r.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "listitem" }; r.QueryParameters.Top = 999; });

var publicDocuments = allDocuments.Value.Where(m => m.ListItem?.Fields.AdditionalData.Where(j => j.Key == "Public" && j.Value.ToString().ToLower() == "true").ToList().Count > 0).ToList();
```

ListItem is always null for every item on the v5.x code

What am I missing?

Any questions feel free to ask

Cheers

Kyle

Comment: Most likely the issue is the type of authentication has changed.  Read Authentication at your link.

Comment: Hi jdweng. I've managed to get my authentication working in v5. I just didn't add/mention it in my sample code above. Apologies.

Comment: Did you upgrade both client and server?  Did you do a clean build?  You have meta data where the meta data gets serialized on client and then deserialized in server when sending and opposite when receiving.  The serialization has to be the same on both ends of the connection.